# re-rendered attribute in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have a form like below :

```
<h:form id="x" prependId="false">

      <h:dataTable id="v" value="#{userBean.cdManagerCollection}" var="cd" 
         border="1">

            <f:facet name="header">
                Test Table 
            </f:facet>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Name" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:inputText id="title" value="#{cd.title}"  />
            </h:column>                                                     
        </h:dataTable>

        <input type="hidden" id='btnName' name="btnName" value="Apply"/>
        <a4j:commandButton  id="btn" value="SUBMIT" action="#{userBean.processCD}" reRender="x"/>

</h:form>
```

My question is , when I submit a form using a4j:command button and then re-render the same, does the request parameter (btnName in this case which is hidden),  is available to access ? (means through facescontext environment variable ? )

Basically , I need to decide on data while returning ${userBean.cdManagerCollection} based on request parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value if your `<input>` element will of course be available as an attribute of HTTP request. In other words, that parameter will be visible as a String in your action method `userBean.processCD` via a call to:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("btnName");
```

If you would like to take the JSF approach, which I strongly recommend, you would bind the `value` attribute of a `<h:inputHidden>` tag to a bean property so that JSF could do the input transformation (validation, conversion, property setting, etc.) on its own:

```
<h:inputHidden id="btnName" value="#{userBean.btnName}"/>
```

with a property of your managed bean:

```
private String btnName;//getter+setter
```

Answer (score -1):

If you'd read the parameter for `btnName` from the `userBean` you would have that parameter already in your `userBean`:

```
<input type="hidden" id="btnName" name="btnName" value="#{userBean.btnParameter}" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately that won't set the managed bean's property, it would only prepopulate hidden input during initial page load, by reading the property. It has nothing to do with OP's problem, which is opposite to what you're doing.